# Create bootable USB drive from binary file?

Tags: unix, binary, bootloader

I have a bin file that I compiled from ASM source via `nasm -f bin -o helloworld.bin helloworld.asm`. How can I write `helloworld.bin` to a USB flash drive. **I *DO NOT* want to write it to a floppy disk!** I wouldn't mind using Unix or MS-DOS or a third-party software to do this, as long as it writes to a **USB Flash Drive** and **NOT** a floppy disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `dd(1)` ? Something like

```
dd if=helloworld.bin of=/dev/sdc
```

Comment: @Mohit Deshpande I just saw your comment; you might be able to use rawrite on windows.

Comment: For me it worked on the QEMU but not on the USB real hardware: https://github.com/cirosantilli/x86-bare-metal-examples/blob/2b79ac21df801fbf4619d009411be6b9cd10e6e0/bios_hello_world.S Shows nothing on screen.